# We need a notification system for voters after an edit was made to a voted-on post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing, voting

Comments are meant to help the original poster to refine a question or an answer.

If a poster listens to this advice or criticism and does edit post, the quality of the post is thought to improve. Sometimes, if not often, it does improve.

Meanwhile, the voting train has already left the platform and even if grave problems in the post *were* addressed or even resolved, many voters do not return to question.

Voting is completely unrestricted, without any real guidelines. The above suggestion would do nothing to people that just "made up their mind" or came only here because something was featured on the Hot Network Questions list (if this would be an internal site-only feature).

Without a feature like this, some vital parts of the raison d'etre of comments and edits is severely hampered.

There appears to be a conscious decision on this explicit feature request for StackExchange already. But that SE design decision was a while ago. Having a picture of H:SE position of this may document our need/want or collective disinterest in this feature to the SE devselopers.

Comment: Why is this important? If a post is actually improved, it will get the recognition it deserves _eventually_. It may not be from the same people who voted on the initial version, but why does this matter?

Answer (score 3):

This is a network design, not a History.SE specific issue. [It had been requested on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/261831) years ago but was [declined by SE staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52628/261831). There's nothing we can actually do about this here, whether or not we think it's a necessary feature.

Comment: My thinking here was that the SE design decision was a while ago. Having a picture of H:SE position of this may document our need/want or collective disinterest in this feature to the SE devs.