# Dealing with edited answers

Tags: bug

I believe this has been touched on before, but am wondering if there is a mechanism for alerting users to an answer which has been edited? Using the only polite example, I might post an answer people kindly up vote. I may then edit it to add something monumentally silly - but the up votes will remain the same, I suspect. Is this an S:E issue?

Comment: Related: [We need a notification system for voters after an edit was made to a voted-on post](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3693/26786)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but according to the answer to [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262515/notification-on-answer-updates), if you favorite a question (click the little star next to it), you should receive notifications *on your profile page* when it **or any of its answers** is updated.

It looks like its not the typical "inbox" notification, so that solution requires you to know to reload your profile page to check for updates, but its something.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is helpful. I take it that doesn't apply if you've just up voted an answer?

Comment: Well again, I haven't tried it myself, so I wouldn't know. Someone could try it out and report back...

Comment: I "tried", but I am unsure whether I understand it correctly: I receive an inbox-like counter on the fav-tab, but that then has to be sorted for activity? Quite cumbersome, if that's how it is supposed to work. – I thought this only shows if someone else faved the Q… The meta-post has that sorted for newest.